# How to extract the folder containing the file in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying yo extract  filename from a column containing paths.

```
C:\program file \Java\bin\abc.txt
D:\program files \Jen\bin\tin\Sys.ex
```

I want to extract like `bin` from first row and `tin` from the second row. ie I want to extract the folder in which the files residing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
with tbl as
 (select 'D:\program files \Jen\bin\tin\Sys.ex' hello
    from dual)
select 
regexp_substr(hello, '[^\]+', 1, regexp_count(hello, '[^\]+', 1)-1) folder  from tbl
```

above query returns the folder where the file resides.